# Adding strings to Rails JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view

I need to output custom JSON in order to be backwards compatible with existing software, which is written in Javascript, so I need to wrap my JSON with "parseDate(" at the beginning of it, and ");" at the end of it.

I tried doing it in controller like this

```
def index
@data = Data.all
@products = Product.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render :json => { :products => {:product => @data.name}}}
end
```

end

And then specify it in the view:

app/views/products.json.erb

```
<%= p "parseData(" %>
<%= render :json %>
<%= p "};" %>
```

But it outputs pure JSON completely skipping both "parseData(" and ");", why? How do I make JSON to be printed in the middle of the view and then append strings to the top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON renderer supports a callback option.

```
format.json { render :json => { :products => {:product => @data.name }}, :callback => 'parseDate' }
```

You can read the implementation in the [`renderer.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L94) source code.